Sending Opentelemetry traces and spans to Datadog from a Vercel hosted NextJS app through a custom OTEL Exporter/Collector
For the past week, I've been trying to send opentelemetry data from my NextJs app to Datadog through a custom OTEL Collector. I can see some error logs in DD, but they don't have trace IDs, and the OTEL spans I'm seeing in my local console are not in DD.
Has anyone gotten/tried to get this stack work? I contacted Vercel support about it, and they replied:

Our internal team has confirmed that the reason you’re unable to view traces or spans is due to the feature being in private beta. This applies even if you’re using custom OTEL exporters, as the necessary setup for data forwarding on Vercel’s side has not been completed for all customers.

I find this hard to believe, as it would kind of defeat a big part of why we're using OTEL, the vendor agnostic implementation. Vercel only offers integrations for New Relic and Datadog (DD support is only for their Enterprise customers as well). Based on their answer, if we're not using either of those providers, we won't be able to get any tracing for applications hosted in Vercel?
Any way, my question is, has someone been successful with getting OTEL instrumentation working with a custom collector and Vercel?
For reference, this is my instrumentation.ts file:
import { OTLPHttpJsonTraceExporter, registerOTel } from '@vercel/otel';

export async function register() {
  registerOTel({
    serviceName: 'my-service',
    traceExporter: new OTLPHttpJsonTraceExporter({
      url: 'url-to-the-custom-collector',
    }),
  });
}


Tried sending OTEL tracing and spans to Datadog through a custom OTEL Collector.
Expected to see OTEL traces and spans in Datadog.
Only saw few error logs. Local OTEL traces are not making it to DD.
EDIT: The error logs in Datadog:


Hello Antii, could you share the error logs you are getting? Are the spans reaching your Collector?

Hi Juliano! The error logs I mentioned are normal logs in Datadog. Sorry I should have been more specific.
Yes, the spans are reaching the collector.

If I were you, I'd first make it absolutely sure that the OTEL collector setup is working properly by sending logs to it from somewhere else, like a standard console application on your own machine. Once that is validated, I'd look into what you are using for instrumentation on the NodeJS side, where it appears the problem is. I agree with you that the response from Vercel's team makes no sense at all: I think they misunderstood your ask and are probably talking about native platform logs, not application logs.

Something else to keep in mind, is that usually it's the tracing instrumentation that introduces a TraceId into the mix, and that's where the trace ID value is obtained for logs as well. Do you have any high level tracing enabled for your main web framework? In C#, that would be the AspNetCore instrumentation that generates the spans with the IDs, and then any logs that happen inside of those spans get the same trace ID for correlation purposes.

Hey Antii! If the data is arriving at the collector, I'd assume things are properly set in the application side. You collector has to have 2 datadog components configured, the datadog exporter and the datadog connector. do you have those 2?
Is your collector raising any errors?
Also, I saw that there is vector in the log entry, are you using Vector or is just a coincidence on the name?
